# NativeScript Android error: java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative

Tags: java, android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to add a payment library (https://github.com/mayubao/Android-Pay) for android like this:

```
let activity = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
    let d = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    let time = d.toString()

    let  wechatPayReq = new io.github.mayubao.pay_library.WechatPayReq.Builder()
            .with(activity) //activity instance
            .setAppId('wxd930ea5d5a258f4f') //wechat pay AppID
            .setPartnerId("1900000109")//wechat pay partner id
            .setPrepayId("1101000000140415649af9fc314aa427")//pre pay id
            .setNonceStr("1101000000140429eb40476f8896f4c9")
            .setTimeStamp(time)//time stamp
            .setSign("7FFECB600D7157C5AA49810D2D8F28BC2811827B")//sign
            .create();
//2. send the request with wechat pay
io.github.mayubao.pay_library.PayAPI.getInstance().sendPayRequest(wechatPayReq);
```

But I am getting following error:

```
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[])
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1043)
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:925)
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:912)
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:896)
08-19 10:40:50.627  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:888)
08-19 10:40:50.695  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
08-19 10:40:50.695  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1043)
08-19 10:40:50.696  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:925)
08-19 10:40:50.696  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:912)
08-19 10:40:50.696  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:896)
08-19 10:40:50.696  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:888)
08-19 10:40:50.698  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
08-19 10:40:50.698  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1043)
08-19 10:40:50.698  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:925)
08-19 10:40:50.698  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:912)
08-19 10:40:50.698  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:896)
08-19 10:40:50.698  4706  4706 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:888)
```

Environement:

```
tns --version
3.1.3

"tns-android": {
      "version": "3.1.1"
    }
```

In where I am doing wrong? Please advice me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to pass ApplicationContext instated of Activity. So the solution is:

```
import * as app from 'application';    
let activity = app.android.foregroundActivity;
```

Also make sure that wechat app is install in device.